# PHP Insert large amount of values issue

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, insert, loader

Im currently writing a php loader to my mySQL database .
The user enter user|password and write the database table he want to insert to , and select a region from

The form action goes to database.php to do the insert using POST

my code in database.php is:

```
$region = $_POST["region"];
$tablename = $_POST["tableName"]; 

$accounts = explode(PHP_EOL, $_POST["accountlist"]);

$quantity = sizeof($accounts);
// Batch size, calc iterations
$batchSize = 500;

for($idx=0;$idx*$batchSize < $quantity; $idx++){
    $accountsPartial = array_slice($accounts, $idx*$batchSize, $batchSize);

    // Prepare the Query
    $query = "INSERT INTO $tablename (username, password, region) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
    // Create the multiple value placeholder
    $db = $db->prepare($query);


    foreach($accountsPartial as $item){
        $i = 1;
        list($user, $pass) = explode("|", $item);
        $db->bindValue($i++, trim($user));
        $db->bindValue($i++, trim($pass));
        $db->bindValue($i++, trim(strtoupper($region)));
        $db->execute();
    }
}
```

My problem is when I sent more then 500 Values , only 500 accounts getting Insereted.
I would love to get some help and suggestions how to solve this issue
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should be preparing your statement outside the loops. Doing it inside the loop `for` defeats the purpose of preparing statements in the first place. But at least you're doing it inside the `foreach`, so there's that, at least. Plus. why batchsize at all? If you want to insert all of the records, then just split your array and loop on the entire thing.

Comment: When you step through this in a debugger, where does it fail?  The observed result is that it stops at 500, and the code pretty strongly implies a "batch size" of 500.  I doubt that's a coincidence.  Perhaps the logic for moving on to the next "batch" is either not working as intended or you misinterpreted the intent?

Comment: Why care about a "batch size" at all if you are inserting one row at a time? It's not like you are inserting multiple rows at a time and parallelizing execution of large batch queries or anything of that sort to where batching is even a complexity you should add.

Answer (score 1):

Your looping code is basically useless. Since you want to insert ALL of the data from the POST, you should be doing this:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO $tablename (username, password, region) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
// Create the multiple value placeholder
$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
$stmt->bindValue(1, $user);
$stmt->bindValue(2, $pass);
$stmt->bindValue(3, $region)

$region = trim(strtoupper($region));

foreach($accountsPartial as $item){
    list($user, $pass) = explode("|", $item);
    $user = trim($user);
    $pass = trim($pass);

    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Note the binding of the variables **OUTSIDE** the loop, and binding to the actual variables, not the results of the trim() calls.

As well, as written, your code is deleting your database connection, by using the same variable to hold your prepared statement as the db connection itself:

```
$db = $db->prepare(...);
```

will nuke your DB connection, making the rest of the code moot.

Comment: Hi , thanks for your answer , I tried using your code but now its not even loading 1 account , im probarly doing something wrong(im new to php so sorry for that) , Im not sure what my $accountsPartial should contain when im using your code , can you write me the whole code for your solution. Also , inside the foreach I dont need to add $region = trim($region) ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should use a `do {} while ()` loop cause when you want to insert 600 instead of 500 the `$idx = 2` and `$idx * $batchSize = 1000 < 600` and is exiting the loop.

Comment: I changed it to do {} while{} but it still not loading .. can you edit my code to do{} while{} and post it maybe i made a mistake? thanks in advance!